# So what would you do in this situation?

Tags: field-recording, preparation

http://www.foxnews.com/health/2011/05/18/cdc-warns-public-prepare-zombie-apocalypse/?test=latestnews

Would you grab your field recording kit?

Would you modify a shotgun or a shovel to have a mic on the end?

Are you prepared?

Comment: A shotgun on your shotgun perhaps?

Comment: DAMN I love this forum. :-)

Comment: for proper boom mic'ing be sure to take your titanium windscreen basket and blood stain resistant windjammer.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless lav your 4 slowest, yet-to-be-zombified friends. That way you get the attack, the change, and the subsequent zombie walla. Changing the battery would suck though.

Comment: @Steve - I like the way you think. lol Good one!

Answer (score 1):

I bet real life zombies don't sound as cool as the ones in movies. But i guess you could buy some sheep brains or something, then dangle them above the zombies, and train them to do some loop group for you.

Comment: "Does anyone know any German?" "gggrrwWWEGWAAAWWEwwww" "I need some German walla for the next scene..." "gggrrrRRRRRHHHHSHHSHh" "This loop group is always a pain to work with..."

Comment: @Roger - Before long we'd likely have to have certified Zombie Wranglers on location.

Comment: @Syndicate Yeah, and then they'd form a Zombie Union and we'd have to give them more brains... Organic, locally grown, low sodium brains. You know what? Zombies would be terrible talent.

Comment: @Roger - Yeah, talk about "character actors", sheesh! The logistics behind trying to starve them and taunt them with raw flesh to get them to moan/groan more for ADR with a wrangler and having to invoice union talent is already giving me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna stack up enough batteries for power so you guys can take backups and fall asleep knowing your data is safe (even if you awake as a Zombie the next morning).

No free lunch. SFX swap for power supply.

;)

Answer (score 0):

i would sacrifice my limbs to get a contact mic down one of their throats

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd get some good distance ambiences from the top of a building, then when I finally needed to move, rig up some sort of binaural-head array on my helmet (not going outside without body armor, football pads, something!) to record more up-close stuff as I fight my way through the teeming masses of the undead.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are crazy! I would rather prepare some wireless bombs, throw it in their midst or stuff it down their throats and get an awesome recording while killing a zombie!

Answer (score 0):

remote microphones embedded in bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Attach as many bugs as possible to different zombies and start recording.

http://www.advanced-intelligence.com/audio.html#!au046

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up that zooming microphone they have above the Staples Center basketball court above the center of the town so I could get all subsequent recordings with the ability to zoom in on each attack - all from the safety of my very own zombie-shelter.

http://www.lakersnation.com/staples-center-has-a-new-microphone-tmz-would-love/2010/10/05/